# SQL Server Bulk Insert error - data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I'm not a pro in this but I'm trying to do a bulk insert (from csv to SQL Server) but I'm getting some errors:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Year).
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Here is the code I have used:

```
BULK INSERT [dbCen_Staging].dbo.[dc1]
FROM "C:\Newfolder\dc.csv"
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    MAXERRORS = 0,
    --DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
    BATCHSIZE=250000,
    KEEPIDENTITY
)
GO
```

So wondering why I'm making a mistake, or if anyone else has a better idea on how to insert a few csv files with 900 millions rows each to SQL Server table. Any on-premise or Azure cloud solution maybe? Because speed matters a lot.

Thanks all

Comment: If speed matters you probably shouldn't be using CSV files in the first place. Native byte encoding is probably even faster. Either way: if you want to do CSV with `BULK` then you need `FORMAT = 'CSV'` which is only supported on newer versions. Do not try to do this without that option, it won't work properly

Comment: thanks @Charlieface , I will add that argument and see if it works. however, can you please explain more on 'native byte encoding' method? because I have my data in multiple huge csv files.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: When the source data is coming from another SQL Server then native byte encoding works best. If the source data is coming from somewhere else, though, have you tried specifying a [Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server) to declare the mapping of columns between the CSV file and the target table and which collation(s) should be used?